# Sonata Admin locale change with admin user's locale

Tags: symfony, admin, locale, sonata

I build a i18n admin site with sonata admin bundle. Now i wanna change my locale and translation with admin user's locale set. Such as , i have two admin users one is en（userA), and another is zh(UserB). user's locale is set en/zh  in User admin dashboard respectively。

My admin service ：

```
services:
    sonata.admin.post:
        class: Acme\StoreBundle\Admin\PostAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Project", label_translator_strategy: sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product
            - ~
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [AcmeStoreBundle]]
            - [ setLabelTranslatorStrategy, [ @sonata.admin.label.strategy.native ]]
```

Then my Resources/translations/AcmeStoreBundle.en.xliff and Resources/translations/AcmeStoreBundle.zh.xliff just like so：

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>label.product.name</source>
                <target>Product Name</target>  ##---> zh is diffrent here!!!
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Then, i loggin admin by UserA, the message (product name ) is ok. But i loggin by UserB  the message is still en locale( product name) .  Of course， I can change the global locale in parameters.yml (%locale%) for userB, But this is not good for userA .

So, how can i change my site's locale(message or translation) with diffrent admin's user locale ?
Thanks  in advance.

Comment: Where do you store the User's locale, in the database?

Comment: Sorry forget mention that .I used the sonata [user bundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/index.html) to add my site administrator, then i modify user's profile(locale) in sonata admin user dashboard. And I also can saw the change result in database table(fos_user_user)  is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend the login success handler and set the user's locale in the session. For example:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    login_success_handler:
        parent: security.authentication.success_handler
        class:  MyVendor\MyBundle\LoginSuccessHandler
```

**UPDATE:** Make sure to point to this listener in your security.yml:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                success_handler: login_success_handler
```

Then add login success handler class:

```
class LoginSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $locale = $token->getUser()->getLocale()

        $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        $request->setLocale($locale);

        return parent::onAuthenticationSuccess($request, $token);
    }
}
```

Then you could [create a LocaleListener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html) similar to or exactly the same as the one in the Symfony documentation.  The only difference is, if you will never define `_locale` in your routes you could change:

```
if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
    $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
} else {
    $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
}
```

to just

```
$request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
```

Comment: That's OK .Thank a lot. By the way , The method onAuthenticationSuccess should return a Response. So I add `return parent::onAuthenticationSuccess( $request, $token );` in the method last line;

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I was kind of condensing just the relevant parts of the code, but it makes sense to show that.  That is the exact line you would want to return and I edited my post to contain that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jason. I did that as your hint.But , the login_success_handler seem not be called completely。

my config.yml:

```
services:
    login_success_handler:
        parent: security.authentication.success_handler
        class:  Acme\StoreBundle\EventListener\LoginSuccessHandler

    acme_locale.locale_listener:
        class: Acme\StoreBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
        arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

And the src/Acme/StoreBundle/EventListener/LoginSuccessHandler.php

```
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class LoginSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $locale = $token->getUser()->getLocale();
        file_put_contents('/tmp/login.log', $locale, FILE_APPEND);  ## I can't find the log file
        $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        $request->setLocale($locale);
    }
}
```

And src/Acme/StoreBundle/EventListener/LocaleListener.php

```
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }
        $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

What's wrong with me? Thanks.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention you have to put to your new success handler in the security.yml file.  I updated my post to include this information.